# Look up current positions and velocities of solar system objects

Tags: the-moon, the-sun, solar-system, earth, n-body-simulations

I am working on an orbital dynamics code and, for fun, I would like to model the Sun-Earth-Moon system with my code.  I can look up the masses of each object just fine, as well as average distances and relative velocities (which I can also calculate).  However, I would like to model the Sun-Earth-Moon system in great detail.  I would like to know the positions and velocities of each object on any given day (today works just fine) so that I can represent the orbits of these objects with great accuracy, hopefully even reproducing their actual ellipticity.  Where can I find values for:

- current Sun-Earth distance
- current Earth-Moon distance
- current Sun-Moon angular separation
- current velocity of Earth relative to Sun (or relative to Sun-Earth(-Moon?) center of mass)
- current velocity of Moon relative to Earth

and, maybe even

- current velocity of Sun relative to Sun-Earth(-Moon?) center of mass.

Is there any resource that provides these current values?

Comment: If you're into Mathematica, https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/ASTRO/playground2.m

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any resource that provides these current values?

Yes. The [JPL HORIZONS on-line solar system data and ephemeris computation service](http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/?horizons) provides these values, and much more.

Comment: If you need continuous values, you can also look at NASA's SPICE files.

Comment: @barrycarter -which is http://naif.jpl.nasa.gov